# How can I create a clickable hyperlink in DocuSign after the document is complete

Tags: hyperlink, docusignapi

1. I have created a hyperlink in DocuSign like it is described here https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-to-create-a-hyperlink-in-DocuSign. Sent it to email and opened. All created hyperlinks were clickable. But after a document is complete hyperlinks can't be clicked. How can I create clickable hyperlinks? This is intended behavior or if something is missing in the API call?
2. Embedded doc hyperlinks are clickable after a document is complete but can't be clicked when signing.
   Why it clickable only when signing?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks during the signing session are more of a DocuSign interface trick than anything else - they are not embedded into the PDF and thus become inactive.

In order to get a hyperlink that's clickable outside of DocuSign, you'll need to edit the underlying PDF to include it there. Since PDF links aren't clickable inside DocuSign, you can place a hyperlink tag in the same location (such as a text box with white-colored underscores) so that it's clickable either way.